# How to remove boring message from itunes

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I try to remove from itunes this boring message window that appears periodically :

[image]

I have never had this message before and I don't know how to desactive it.
I have unchecked the following options into "itunes > preferences" :

[image]

Any help is welcome

Comment: Does it say "your session with iTunes will expire" ?

Comment: -@Buscar웃 yes, the english traduction of this boring window is : "your session iTunes has expired"

Comment: Sorry, that is the iTunes `Store`, not the iTunes on you computer, so you connection with iTunes Store expires?

Comment: yes, do you know how to remove it ?

Comment: In iTunes menu bar go to Account and `Sign out` of iTunes store. That will stop that message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My French is bit rusty, but if i understand it right, that message is from

> iTunes Store

, telling you the session has ended.

To stop that message do following.

In iTunes menu bar got to Account, then Sign out.

[image]

Comment: into iTunes > Preferences ? I don't see the label "Account" ?

Comment: No, not iTunes preference, in the the iTunes menu bar, File, Edit, Song ...Account

Comment: ok,  I have an old version of iTunes, that's why I have not this Account label in menu bar

Comment: do you know what version you have

Comment: version 12.6.2.20

Comment: I have 12.8 and pretty sure yours should have the Account in the Menu Bar, if not click on Apple (top left) then on App Store, then sign out there

Comment: great, I found it with Apple top left menu. thanks !

Comment: @youpilat13 you are welcome